# How do I provide configuration name dynamically during DSC compilation?

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have configuration named `sqlconfig` defined in file called `sqlconfig.ps1` which I want to compile while passing DSC data structure and name of configuration itself to it. Sample code is below

```
$sqlData =
@{
   AllNodes    =
   @(
      @{
         NodeName                    = "*"
         PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword = $true
      }
    );
}
. $PSScriptRoot/sqlconfig.ps1
$configName = 'sqlconfig'
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $name } -ArgumentList  "-ConfigurationData $sqlData"
```

Code above does not work and do not compile configuration to MOF file.
Neither `Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { "$name -ConfigurationData $sqlData" }`

Comment: Did you try using `Start-DscConfiguration`?

Comment: I just need to compile to MOF file, I don't need to apply

Comment: then maybe `Publish-DscConfiguration` might help? Hope you tried that.